# Select type validate required not working in jsgrid

Tags: php, jsgrid

I am using country and state master with jsgrid in php mysql database, In state php call country master dropdown with country id name field and state name text field.Validate required syntax is not working in country_id field.the js script is below.Appreciate anyone help this issue.
$(function() {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "countries_drop.php"
}).done(function(countries) {
   countries.unshift({ Country_Id: "0", Country_Name: "" });
$('#States_table').jsGrid({

 width: "100%",
 height: "600px",

 filtering: true,
 inserting:true,
 editing: true,
 sorting: true,
 paging: true,
 autoload: true,
 pageSize: 10,
 pageButtonCount: 5,
 deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete data?",

 controller: {
  loadData: function(filter){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "states.php",
    data: filter
   });
  },
  insertItem: function(item){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "states.php",
    data:item
   });
  },
  
  updateItem: function(item){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "states.php",
    data: item
   });
  },
  deleteItem: function(item){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "states.php",
    data: item
   });
  },
 },

 fields: [
    { 
    autosearch: true, 
    name: "Country_Id", 
    title: "Country", 
    type: "select", 
    width: 100, 
    items: countries, 
    valueField: "Country_Id", 
    textField: "Country_Name" ,
    align: "left",
    //selectedIndex: -1, 
    validate: "required"
    },
  {
   name: "State_Id",
type: "hidden",
css: 'hide'
  },
  {
   name: "State_Name", 
type: "text", 
width: 150, 
validate: "required"
  },
  {
   type: "control"
  }
 ]

});
```

});

});

I tried to insert statename without country code selection showing blank, and with country code selection data is showing, so i want to validate country selection before insert the record.

Comment: This is not a PHP issue, it is a JS one. Tag is erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
countries.unshift({ Country_Id: "0", Country_Name: "" });
```

to

```
countries.unshift({ Country_Id: "", Country_Name: "" });
```

as `0` is a valid value for text type